# Can I use a first difference variable as dependent variable in a panel regression even if it contains both positive and negative values?

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, causality, difference-in-difference

Can I still use a first difference variable as the outcome variable to run a panel (say, diff-in-diff) regression? For example, my dependent variable is defined as $Y_{i,t} = M_{i,t} - M_{i,t-1} - P_{i,t}$, namely, [change score](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Defending%20and%20Extending%20Difference%20Score%20Methods%20&btnG=) in psychology and management where $M_{i,t}$ and $P_{i,t}$ denote the total population registration and natural population growth at city i in year t and $Y_{i,t}$ denotes the overall permanent migration change. $Y_{i,t}$ certainly contains both positive and negative values.

My understanding is that if $A_{i,t} = M_{i,t} − C_{i,t}$, then $A_{i,t}$ is called difference score as suggested by [Edward (1995)](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Edwards%2C%20J.%20R.%20%281995%29.%20Alternatives%20to%20difference%20scores%20as%20dependent%20variables%20in%20the%20study%20of%20congruence%20in%20organizational%20research.%20Organizational%20behavior%20and%20human%20decision%20processes%2C%2064%283%29%2C%20307-324.&btnG=). Directly estimating $A_{i,t}$ might be problematic because we cannot disentangle the effects on $M_{i,t}$ and $C_{i,t}$ from independent variable. However, in my case, I used scores on identical variables over time. I do not actually need the effects on $M_{i,t}$ and $M_{i,t-1}$; rather, I just adopt the net effect, $Y_{i,t}$, the net migration.

I am not sure if it could be methodologically problematic if I directly use $Y_{i,t}$ as the outcome variable. I'd like to hear your opinions.

Any help will be truly appreciated and, of course, Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the variable $Y_{it}$ certainly you can define the first difference $\Delta Y_{it} := Y_{it}-Y_{it-1}$ and you can use it in a panel data regression. This does not depend on how $Y_{it}$ itself is calculated.

Offcourse how $Y_{it}$ itself is defined/calculated may impact on, whether you can relate it meaningfully and in interesting ways to theories within your field of expertice but that is a question beyond statistics.

Comment: Hi Jesper, 
So you reckon it should be fine to use first difference as dependent variable without putting any change on independent variable if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Define »fine«. If by fine you mean that the estimation theory usually used in panel data setting apllies then yes it is just fine. But i wouldnt know whether such a regression would be meaningfull in your field of expertice.

Comment: Pls. Accept and upvote if you find the answer useful.